# group multiple rows into single row multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My data tables look like this:

User table:

```
UserID Parameter Value
1      1         1
2      1         1
1      2         2
```

Parameter Table:

```
ID Name
1 "Age"
2 "Gender"
```

Value Table:

```
ParameterID ValueID Name
1           1       "17"
2           1       "Male"
```

Is it possible to group the user table into single rows with multiple columns to look something like this?

```
UserID Age Gender
1      1   1
```

Comment: In the User table, you have parameter 3, but there is no Parameter ID=3  in the Parameter table?!

Comment: What database do you use? Have you tried any query?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a `PIVOT` query.  This is very specific to your platform, please tag the question with your DBMS (Mysql, MS SQL, Oracle..etc)

Comment: Okay sorry about that. I am using MSSQL 2014 - C# ASP.net MVC5